# How to run a c or c++ program on a Android Device like Samsung galaxy tab?

Tags: c++, android, c, native

Hi im wondering how to execute a simple helloworld c or c++ program on a Android phone i googled it but i dont find any crystal clear working methods guys direct me in this....

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) (Native Development Kit).

The NDK package also contains [some demos](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples) you can compile and run.

Answer (score 2):

This requires some perseverance on your part to figure this out.

As peoro has said, you need the Android NDK but that really is only the beginning. You will need to move your project relative to the Android NDK directory, mark up your code with the "native" keyword, create some make-files, use these to generate headers for the JNI (Java Native Interface) and then create accompanying cpp files into which you paste your code.

This is the outline.

Good instructions (i.e. that were good enough for me to succeed at this with C) are here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/25/boosting-android-performance-using-jni/

as well as the Android docs/Android NDK instructions themselves

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

It is a pain to do this *but* if it saves you time overall/gains you critical performance then it is well worth it and very satisfying. On the other hand, if your code is fairly short and you're not after critical performance you are better off just translating it into Java. That's not hard.

Comment: Thanks guys appreciate that :)

Comment: @AshokJeev If any of these answers is correct, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Check the link to see how and why.